# How to move emails from mailing lists into automatically created sub-folders

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I am tired of creating/updating a new rule each time I subscribe to a new company mailing list. And I reached the rules size limit so at some point I am forced to combine them.

Is there a way to tell Outlook "toss all emails into a sub-folders of X where sub-folder name is the name of the mailing list"? I am ok having this as the catch-all rule at the end of the list.

Comment: Would you consider using search folders instead of actually moving each email? You could have one rule that moves emails into a Mailing List folder, and then individual search folders for each company.

Comment: Other options are to use an add-in, or write VBA code.

Comment: I would have to create a search folder for each mailing list then. I feel like it's such a basic thing - reading different mailing lists in separate folders, and grouping emails by lists should not be a manual setup each time a new list is being added...

Comment: No way. You can't. Either use VBA or third-pary add-in.

Answer (score 0):

Use a rule to put all mailing list emails into one folder. In that folder, use the field chooser to add the "To" field to the columns, then group by that field. Now each mailing list can be viewed in an expandable/collapsible 'section' within the view.
(you might be able to group by To and then Subject or conversation too)